# Get Date type object in format in java

Tags: java, date

As we know we can get date using  `Java.util.Date` or `Calender` instance or by using `GregorianCalendar` instance .

Using class '`SimpleDateFormat`' we can `parse()` or `format()` function  our `Date` or `String`.

As we know using `parse()` or `format()` function we get output as a `String` only.

Is there any option available in java to get `Date` instance in particular format like 'yyyy-MM-dd' or any other format, but final output should be of `Date` type with this format ?

Answer (score 1):

[Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) doesn't have a format at all. It is just the representation of time since the standard base time known as *The Epoch*, namely *January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT*.

You can only get a String representation of the Date in the format required using the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Also, `parse()` method of SDF parses the String representation of the Date to a Date object. `format()` is the method which gives the formatted String representation of the Date object.

Comment: Forget about 'SimpleDateFormat' is there any option available to get Date object in any format?  As I need to pass date object with particular format in external API?

Comment: @user3097955 - The very first line of my answer should answer your doubt. *`Date` does not have a format of its own*.

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `Instant`

As others said, a `java.util.Date` represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of milliseconds. A `java.util.Date` has no format at all.

You can convert `Date` objects to a `java.time.Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Assign a time zone in which getting a date makes sense in your scenario. A time zone is crucial to determining a date; for any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

## `LocalDate`

Now if you want to work with date-only values without a time-of-day and without a time zone, extract a `LocalDate` object from the `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

## Generating strings

To generate a String representing this `LocalDate` value in the format you requested, simply call `toString`. That format of YYYY-MM-DD is a standard ISO 8601 format. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. Do not confuse a formatted string with the date-time object. A date-time object *has no format*, only strings have a format.

```
String output = ld.toString();
```

If you want other formats, search Stack Overflow for the class `DateTimeFormatter`.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Answer (score 0):

**No** it is fixed in `toString()` method of `Date` class, You could extend `Date` if you strictly want this functionality

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the `java.util.Date` class, and override the default `toString()` method. You might implement the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern (or the [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern - I'm not certain if there's a distinction really).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is no.  The classes `Date` and `GregorianCalendar` don't include a format - you have to have the format separately, either as a `String` or a `SimpleDateFormat`.

If you really want to be able to pass an object which has both a date and a format, you could make your own class, which has a `GregorianCalendar` and a `SimpleDateFormat` as fields.  You could give it a `toString` method that formats the `GregorianCalendar` using the `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments suggest your are missing the point that  **a date-time object is not a string**. In both java.util.Date and [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), a date-time is represented as milliseconds since the [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29). In Java 8 java.time.* the date-time may be nanoseconds since Epoch. But none of that has any thing to do with strings. We create strings as output, as a translation of those milliseconds/nanoseconds, to be meaningful to humans.